# what cause the error , when i'm trying to retreive data from database using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get data from my database, I use XAMPP local server
it doesn't display student table into html table
it displays:  `'; } ?>` and the empty table
database name: test, User name: root, no password, table name: student
any response will be appreciated
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    td,th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
 
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test")
           or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM student" ;
  $result = mysqli_query("test", $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['root'] . ' ' . $row[''] . '<br />';
    }
 
  ?> 
   
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Roll Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
               if(!empty($row))
               foreach($row as $rows)
              { 
            ?>
            <tr>
  
                <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['branch']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['roll_no']; ?></td>
  
            </tr>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>


</html>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please provide the text output (copy the response html from the developer tools network menu) that way we can where the error occurs.

Comment: ; } ?>
Name Branch Roll Number

Comment: File has a PHP extension, server has PHP installed, page is being loaded over protocol that server reads (e.g. http(s))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` loop has no ending. You need to add a closure after the row ends:

```
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Also, you have two simicolons on line 1, but that shouldn't change anything.

Edit:

Take a look at this example file:

```
<div>
    <?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    
    foreach ($arr as $value) 
    {
    ?>
        <div><?php print($value * 2); ?></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This correctly outputs:

```
<div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

But without the closing `<?php } ?>` for each number, there is a 500 error.

Comment: that is a mistake , i fix it,, but still table displayed empty, while i have 2 rows in my database

Comment: That would be a fatal error. 500 would be thrown and no output.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should iterate the query result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test")
           or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM student" ;
  $result = mysqli_query("test", $query);

  ?>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Branch</th>
          <th>Roll Number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
          ?>
          <tr>

            <td>
              <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['branch']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['roll_no']; ?>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code fix 50%, now no more errors, but still table displayed empty,

Comment: Heads up, you've got `while ($row = ...`, but referring to `$rows` in each table cell

Comment: The `foreach($row as $rows)` confused me

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the first section

```php
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test")
           or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM student" ;
  $result = mysqli_query("test", $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['root'] . ' ' . $row[''] . '<br />';
    }
 
  ?>
```

The function for [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli-query) takes in a MySQLI resource as the first parameter and the query as the second. It looks like you've got "test" instead of `$mysqli`

When you're calling `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` right below, that's using the response and advancing the internal pointer to the next row, so the next time you call mysqli_fetch_array, it'll return back with the second row! After the while-loop, you've now gone through the entire result set, and `$row` will only be false (or null).

Finally, there is the case of a missing closing } for your foreach-loop.

Based on those, this is one possible way of showing the data, assuming 'name', 'branch' and 'roll_no' are columns on the student table.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test")
            or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM student";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    td,th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Roll Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?></td>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['branch']) ?></td>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['roll_no']) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```